# Docusaurus v2 | Not able to scroll to top on route change

Tags: docusaurus

I am facing a weird issue in Chrome only: If I scroll the page, then click on an item in DocSidebar, the page navigates to a new URL but does not scroll to the top, but on click of second time it does. Any idea about the bad scroll state of the page? Thanks